# Why doesn't VisualStateManager.GoToState work on a control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive-design, visualstatemanager

I am working on a WPF application and trying to make a responsive UI using Visual State Manager as MSDN suggests for UWP responsive design and it works on UWP but not on WPF.

Here is the example I am testing on WPF. It is supposed to change the background of the `StackPanel` to `Red` on start-up.

The XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultState">
                <Storyboard>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <Storyboard >
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Menu" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StackPanel.Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="StackPanelCenetrofPage" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MenuColumnWidth" Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="Menu"
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="Hey"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Frame Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And the C# code:

```cs
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.PreviousSize.Width < 1024) 
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "WideState", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "DefaultState", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: I mean when I run the app it does not change (the Stack Panel Background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotostate?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Call the GoToState method if you are changing states in a control that uses the VisualStateManager in its ControlTemplate. Call the GoToElementState method to change states on an element outside of a ControlTemplate (for example, if you use a VisualStateManager in a UserControl or in a single element).

So you should use `GoToElementState` instead of `GoToState`. The first parameter of `GoToElementState` is the control owning the `VisualStateManager` so you should move the `VisualStateManager` to the `Window` to keep using `this` in the code-behind.

```cs
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.PreviousSize.Width < 1024) {
        var result = VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "WideState", true); // <- Here
    } else {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this, "DefaultState", false);
    }
}
```

On a side note, you cannot animate the `Background` like this. You need to define a `Value` that is a `Brush` and not just a `Color`:

```xml
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
</DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
```

Comment: Thanks, For Animating Background what should I set as " StoryBoard.TargetProperty" ? I tried "(StackPanel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" and got an exception for "property path '(0).(SolidColorBrush)" cannot reslove

Comment: Oh just use `Background` :)